# How to find the number of occurences of a number in a sorted Array in O(logn)

Tags: algorithm, array-algorithms

I have a sorted Array of Integers. Given a number, how to find the number of occurences of that number in O(logn) even the worst case.

Comment: When you hear "sorted array" and "O(logn)", it can only mean binary search. In this case, you will need two binary searches. Also, is this homework?

Comment: Its no homework. I also know that i need to use binary search. I could not come up with a O(log N) algo in the worst case.

Comment: Post what you came up with then, and explain why it is not O(logN). This will help us help you.

Comment: It sure smells like homework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binary search for the number, then binary search for the start and the end of the run.

Answer (score 4):

Do one binary search for the point where all elements to the left are smaller than your number and all to the right are equal or greater and one for the point where all elements are smaller or equal to the left and greater to the right.

In other words: in one search your "test" is `<`, while in the other search the test is `<=`.

Both searches are `log n`, so that's your total.

For example, in C++ the two functions you'd need are `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` - it seems like the existing Java binary search functions (on Collections) always try to look for a specific value, so you probably have to implement the search yourself if you're using that.

It's important that you use a binary search variant that uses only a binary predicate! If you use a variant that checks whether it hit a specific key "by accident" will sometimes terminate too soon for this specific task.

Comment: the `<=` sounds dangerous... are you sure that this does not deteriorate to `O(N)` if the list is made entirely of (or the majority of the list contains) `number` ?

Comment: Yes, I am 100% sure. The only requirement for any predicate is that it has to be monotonically decreasing, i.e. all elements that evaluate to false need to appear after the elements that evaluate to true. This works for both `<n` and `<=n`. Also, with integers, `<=n` is equivalent to `<n+1`.

Answer (score 1):

Search for the insertion points of `number + 0.5` and `number - 0.5` using two binary searches. The number of elements with value `number` in the list is the difference of the positions (indices) of these two insertion points.

Answer (score 0):

Run the function below once as it is and once with the if condition changed to if(a[mid]<=val) and the corresponding changes in the recursive calls. The two values returned are the starting and ending occurence of the particular value.

```
      int  binmin(int a[], int start, int end,int val )
        {
         if(start<end)
            {
            int mid = (start+end)/2;
            if(a[mid]>=val)
            {
                binmin(a,start,mid-1,val);
            }
            else if(a[mid]<val)
            {
                binmin(a,mid+1,end,val);
            }

    }
    else if(start>end)
            return start;



  }
```